# Losing ngtableparam scope in my View

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

For some reason im losing scope of ngtable params in my view , everything in ngtableparams is undefined ( i see in angularjs batarang binding ).

my controller code is

```
this.contractsParams = new ngTableParams({

        defaultSort: 'asc',
        counts: [],
        total: 10, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {                
            this.MyService.query(
               angular.bind( function (data) {
                 debugger;
                 $defer.resolve(data.Data);
            }));
        }

    });
```

also , the getdata is not getting called at all ever.

My View

```
<table ng-table="controller.contractsParams">
<tr ng-repeat="contract in $data">
      <td data-title="'Title'" data-sortable="'Title'">{{contract.Title}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share the code on jsFiddle or Plunker, please?

Comment: yea it's better if we can see how to reproduce bug

Answer (score 0):

The issue of losing scope might be rooted in `ngTableParams` initialization, it takes two objects: **parameters** and  **settings** , have a look in [docs](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/wiki/Configuring-your-table-with-ngTableParams).
So the simple initialization look like :

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
       /* parameters */ 
     {
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, 
        /* settings */
        {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
```

Have look in example [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ISa4xg?p=info) from official site.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by adding this piece to my view

ng-controller="myController as controller"