# AngularJS ng-table reload in controller

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am unable to access *tableview* in my controller using

```
 **$scope.tableview.reload()**

view.html is this.

 <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="SearchListCtrl">

      <input ng-model="titleFilter"> Title Filter: {{ titleFilter }}
      <table ng-table="tableview" show-filter="true" class="table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr><th colspan="3">Book Shelf</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter:titleFilter">
            <td><a href="#/data/{{$index + 1}}" ng-click="editBook(book)" class="thumb">{{$index + 1}}</a></td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">
              {{book.genre}}
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">{{book.title}}</td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">{{book.author}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" ng-click="deleteRow($index)">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                </button>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

controller is this

```
     librarysystemcontroller.controller('SearchListCtrl',
                                     ['$scope',
                                      'Library',
                                      'EditBookService',
                                      '$http',
                                      '$rootScope',
                                      function($scope,
                                               Library,
                                               EditBookService,
                                               $http,
                                               $rootScope) {
            $scope.tableview.reload();
        }]);
```

@scope.tableview is undefined. Isn't this allowed ? The other model elements like ng-model are accessible.

```
Error is this. Is there a problem with the HTML ?

TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined
```

Update: I think my current table is sufficient for my purposes. ng-table seems to require
some configurations that I don't need.

Comment: Assuming librarysystemcontroller is an angular module, there would be no error. However, I do see a missing ] and ) at the end of the controller.

Comment: `ng-table` is a 3rd party module, not a directive built in to angular. it requires an initialization object in order to function correctly, which would be the object that has a `reload()` function on.  I don't see in this code where you created that object, or even reference the 3rd party library?  http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/

Comment: <link href="lib/angular/ng-table.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="lib/angular/ng-table.js"></script>
I have these now but it doesn't work. These are loaded properly.

Comment: yes, but where is the initialization code?

Comment: var module = angular.module('librarysystem',     
    ['ngTable','ngRoute','librarysystemcontroller','libraryServices']);

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan where is initialization of  `ngtableparams `, like [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ISa4xg?p=info) ?

Comment: also have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939837/losing-ngtableparam-scope-in-my-view

Answer (score 0):

in your controller put this "ngTableParams"

```
librarysystemcontroller.controller('SearchListCtrl',
                                     ['$scope',
                                      'Library',
                                      'EditBookService',
                                      '$http',
                                      '$rootScope',
                                      function($scope,
                                               Library,
                                               EditBookService,
                                               $http,
                                               $rootScope,ngTableParams) {
```